# What is the chemical reaction between Ferric Chloride and Baking Soda

Tags: acid-base

Awhile ago I tried to neutralize ferric chloride with baking soda once I had finished using it for PCB etching. Once I added the baking soda it started bubbling up a lot and I assumed it was releasing a gas.

Does anyone have any idea what gas it was releasing? I read different things on different websites and I wasn't sure which one was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baking soda is basically $\ce{NaHCO3}$. The only way it can typically react is by proton transfer; either deprotonation of the hydrogencarbonate in basic solution to give the carbonate anion or protonation to give $\ce{H2CO3}$. The latter is unstable and quickly breaks down into $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ — carbon dioxide and water. It is the carbon dioxide bubbles you see when adding baking soda to neutralise.

Answer (score -2):

FeCl3 or ferric chloride get ionised in water to Fe+3 and Cl-. Fe+3 then reacts with OH- of water forming Fe(OH)3 a brown ppt and H+ of water reacts with the remaining Cl- to make the aqueous solution acidic by forming HCl. If you put baking soda (NaHCO3) i.e. sodium bicarbonate in this ferric chloride solution it will react with hydrochloric acid and will give out CO2 gas as effervescence. That is why gas bubbling is seen. Hope this piece of information will help you.

Comment: Where does the water come from?

Comment: @NilayGhosh It is quite obvious that in the problem stated by Matt121, he has used aqueous solutions, and that is the source.

Comment: He has not mentioned aqueous solution. You are assuming it.

Comment: PCB Etching

Currently used for print circuit board etching of solvents are iron (Ferric Chloride), cupric chloride (Cupric Chloride), alkaline ammonia (Alkaline Ammonia), sulfuric acid hydrogen peroxide (Sulfuric Acid + Hydrogen Peroxide) etching fluid, ammonium persulfate, sulfuric acid – chromic acid etching solution. Like the PCB manufacturing in Fusion PCB of Seeed.
Etching liquid are mainly copper chloride solution, ferric chloride liquid, alkaline etching, acid/hydrogen peroxide (hydrogen peroxide) etching.

Chloride copper etched liquid by chloride copper (CuCl2 Castle, 2H2O) + hydroch

Comment: Hope this will remove ambiguity.